# Text is not set bold with SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android

I want to make a text to be `bold` :

```
public class Formatage {

    public Formatage() {
        super();
    }
    ...
    public static String bold(String text) {

            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
            StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
            ssb.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            return ssb.toString();

    }
    ...
}
```

At runtime when I call the method `String chp = Formatage.bold("some_text");` then when I show the `String` "chp" inside an `AlertDialog` then the text is not bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return `String`, return `CharSequence` or `Spannable` and it should work.

```
public static CharSequence bold(String text) {
   // ...
   return ssb;
}
```

`SpannableStringBuilder`'s `toString()` implementation returns a `String` containing a copy of the chars in this buffer, without markup

Comment: which method of dialog are you using to show the text ?

Comment: Ok I will post a new question to show the code of the Dialog :)

Comment: no, there is no need. My was a genuine question. are you using setMessage ?